# incorporating a formula as a sheet name

Tags: excel, vba

How to create VBA macro that'll incorporate

```
=TEXT(TODAY()-DAY(TODAY()),"MM")
```

and

```
=TEXT(TODAY()-DAY(TODAY()),"YY")
```

for my tab names

I currently complete a report for work every month, and every month the tab names change.
Example: "Keeps MM-YY", "Keeps and Drops MM-YY" or "Keeps 11-22", "Keeps and Drops 11-22".

I want to make a macro that looks for a tab named based off dates "MM-YY" of the previous month.

I tried the following, but had no luck

```
Sub KeepsTab

Dim Month as String
Dim Year as String

Month = TEXT(TODAY()-DAY(TODAY()),"MM")
Year = TEXT(TODAY()-DAY(TODAY()),"YY")

Sheets("Keeps Month-Year").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: VBA is its own separate language from Excel formula syntax; you'd use the `VBA.Strings.Format` function to format a date string in VBA: `Sheets("Keeps" & VBA.Strings.Format(VBA.DateTime.Now, "MM-YY")).Select` should do what you're looking for. And since VBA standard library functions are all global, you could also do `Sheets("Keeps " & Format(Now, "MM-YY")).Select`

Comment: Sheets("Keeps " & Format(Date - Day(Date), "MM-YY")).Select worked beautifully for the previous month's date. Do have a suggestion to get 2 months previous?

Comment: [DateAdd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dateadd-function) can do that.

Comment: @braX DateAdd worked. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is failing as it is explicitly looking for a sheet called "Keeps Month-Year". You could do a quick fix as

```
Sheets("Keeps "& Month & "-" & Year).Select
```

Are you using the functions "WorksheetFunction.Text", "WorksheetFunction.Day" and so on? I believe this are not built-in in VBA, so you may want to check that out.

Last but not least, may I suggest dim-ing a new variable strSheetName so that you concat the name beforehand and then do the lookup?

```
strMonth = WorksheetFunction.Text(WorksheetFunction.Today()-WorksheetFunction.Day(WorksheetFunction.Today()),"MM")
strYear = WorksheetFunction.Text(WorksheetFunction.Today()-WorksheetFunction.Day(WorksheetFunction.Today()),"YY")
strSheetName = "Keeps " & strMonth & "-" & strYear
Thisworkbook.Worksheets(strSheetName).Select
```

Filling in the gaps, of course. This should do it.

Comment: Hey Francisco! Thank you for pointing out the "WorksheetFunction" portion that I was missing. I am new to VBA and am trying to work my way through. I did try the changes you suggested, but I keep getting error a run-time error "438"

Comment: Sub KeepsTab()
    '
    ' KeepsTab Macro
    '

    '
        Dim strSheetName As String
        Dim strMonth As String
        Dim strYear As String
    
        strMonth = WorksheetFunction.Text(WorksheetFunction.Today() -WorksheetFunction.Day(WorksheetFunction.Today()), "MM")
        strYear = WorksheetFunction.Text(WorksheetFunction.Today() - WorksheetFunction.Day(WorksheetFunction.Today()), "YY")
        strSheetName = "Keeps " & strMonth & "-" & strYear
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(strSheetName).Select
    End Sub

Comment: @TuckNorris VBA has it's own date functions that are much faster to type as well: `DateSerial(2022, 12, 15)` = "2022-12-15" || `Date` = "2022-12-19" (same as "Today()") || `Day(Date)` = "19" || `Month(Date)` = "12" || `Year(Date)` = "2022" || `Format(Date, "yyyy-mmm")` = "2022-Dec" (This one is likely SUPER useful to you in this case) || `DateAdd("d", 5, Date)` = "2022-12-24" (you change "d" to "m" or "y" to add months or years instead of days) || [HERE is a good article](https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/date-functions/)

Comment: Also I don't think you can use the WSFunction "Today()" in VBA for some reason. `Format(Date - Day(Date), "mm")` is much safer

Comment: Or `Format(WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(Date, -1), "mm")`

Comment: I feel like I'm getting closer, but the Sheet selection is giving me issues

    
    \\ mBefore = Format(Date - Day(Date), "mm")
    \\ yBefore = Format(Date - Day(Date), "yy")
    \\ Sheets("Keeps " & mBefore & "-" & yBefore).Select